# Python XLWings Anaconda Newbie - Install / Basic issues

Tags: python, excel, dll, anaconda, xlwings

Thanks for your time.  Im an old programmer coming back to Python

I have a new install of Anaconda3, Windows 10 and Microsoft Office 2010

I tried install xlwings via pip straight into Python3 - didn't seem to work

Ive then installed anaconda3, spyder.

Ive installed inside anaconda at the command prompt 
xlwings addin install
xlwings addin update

initially I got an error going into excel, saying 2 spreadsheets of the same name can not be open - I guess that was something to do with when I was trying to get the original python3 / pip/ addin manager to work....
Ive spent all day trying to sort that. It no longer appears in the addin menu (developer), just in the ribbon - xlwings

Ive run a program as per the documentation spyder/python and get Hello xlwings inside excel (created the python and excel spreadsheet with the xlwings quickstart myproject)

But when I try and use a fuction that sends data to python I get an error.  if I click on run main, import functions or restart UDF server I get a missing DLL error

Run Time error 53 - file not found xlwings32.0.19.2.dll.
ive tried copying it to System32, removing the addin (xlwings addin remove) and reinstalling it

I completely unsinstalled Microsoft office and reinstalled it - the addins was still there anyway !

Sorry a lot of explanation for what is actually a DLL issue, but ive been going around and around for hours.

So in summary, I don't had xlwings under the addins/developer in excel, but it does appear on the ribbon.  I can run a python program that puts "hello world" into excel but excel does not recognise the python function and when I try and interact with excel I get a missing .dll error.

What should I do ? rip out python / accoconda etc and start all over again ?

cheers
Older and Greyer !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your problem, I was having the same error with Excel's "sorry you can't have two workbooks of the same name open at the same time" and solved it. The error only happened when the Excel add-in "xlwings" was checked. I fixed the error by moving the location of the xlwings add-in from `C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` where it had automatically put itself to `C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns`.